# Evaluate $\int_a^{+\infty}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot e^{-x}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

We know that $\int_0^{+\infty}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot e^{-x}\mathrm{d}x=\sqrt{\pi}$, but does it have an implicit form(not an infinite sum) of the following integral when $a>0$
$$\int_a^{+\infty}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot e^{-x}\mathrm{d}x=?
$$

Comment: It is not clear what is meant by implicit form. It is definitely not an *elementary function* of $a$.

Comment: @Andre Nicolas Thanks, I just want to know whether there is a closed form of the integral.

Comment: The answer I gave says that if by closed form you mean using elementary functions only, then the answer is no. If you allow "extra" functions, such as the error function, then the answer is yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(a)$ be your integral.  It may be that you are asking for an *explicit* formula for $f(a)$.

The function $f(a)$ can be expressed by using some elementary functions together with the [Error Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) $\operatorname{erf}(t)$. However, $f$ is not an *elementary function* of $a$, basically because its very close relative, the Error Function, is not an elementary function. To do the details of expressing $f(a)$ in terms of the Error Function, make the change of variable $u=\sqrt{x}$.